# Creating a user authentication with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The code worked when the functions was executed under the same "form" event (for e.g by commenting out signin and logout functions statements when executing register function statement). But when I separate this functions under different form event there is no response.

I have two form with class "signin" and "signout" and a  button with class "logout".
Can someone with experience help fix the code cos this is beyond my knowledge. Really appreciate anyone in advance.

```
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
 import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-app.js";
 import {
 getAuth,
 createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
signInWithEmailAndPassword,
signOut,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-auth.js"; 
import {
getDatabase,
set,
ref,
update, 
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.1/firebase-database.js";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration 
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyBxTyIjvXXCDWNJTI8-sFjJfVP2UJOXdIA",
authDomain: "mbconline-c8ae4.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://mbconline-c8ae4-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "mbconline-c8ae4",
storageBucket: "mbconline-c8ae4.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "408267091210",
appId: "1:408267091210:web:c8a1f1eacfd7087b775ef3",
}; 

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const database = getDatabase(app);

const signIn = document.querySelector(".signin");
const signOut = document.querySelector(".signout");
const logOut = document.querySelector(".logout");

signIn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const email = signIn.email.value;
const password = signIn.password.value;

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in
  const user = userCredential.user;
  // ... user.uid
  set(ref(database, "users/" + user.uid), {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })
    .then(() => {
      // Data saved successfully!
      alert("User created successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // The write failed...
      alert(error);
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  // ..
  alert(errorMessage);
});
});

 signOut.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
const email = signOut.email.value;
const password = signOut.password.value;

 signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
  // Signed in
  const user = userCredential.user;
  // ...
  let lgDate = new Date();
  update(ref(database, "users/" + user.uid), {
    last_login: lgDate,
  })
    .then(() => {
      // Data saved successfully!
      alert("User logged in successfully");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // The write failed...
      alert(error);
    });
 })
.catch((error) => {
  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  alert(errorMessage);
});
});

logOut.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
signOut(auth)
 .then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
  alert("Log out successful");
})
.catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
  alert("Log out failed" + error);
});
});
```

Comment: Which specific piece of the code you shared doesn't work. I also recommend debugging it locally, and telling us the outcome of that. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
#Typo
**onst** signIn = document.querySelector(".signin");
const signOut = document.querySelector(".signout");
const logOut = document.querySelector(".logout");
```

there is a typo in the const keyword

Comment: That's just on this site.